# Would it be possible to create a new tab for unanswered questions to give them more attention?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, views, tabs

Would it be possible to make a new tab for each tag that only shows unanswered questions? I've found a connection between the time of the day the question is asked and the number of views. Apparently if it's night in the USA (2-10 ) its most likly my questions will just go under with low views. Even hours later nobody cares about it, because it on page 5 or something like that. I'm from Europe, so if I'm the office in the morning it's most likely most of my SO questions will not be answered.

What I do in such case, is that I delete my old post and ask the same question all over again. That is a bad solution in my opinion. The only other, even worse, solution is, that I try to track the user activity and only ask questions if its high enough.

Comment: @citronas - nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

There's already an "unanswered" tab. (Though it does include questions that have "answers" with no upvotes.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't knew until know that I could apply tag filters to that option. That makes me guess that it isn't as intuitive as it was designed to be. The problem does not stop with me having found the solution. The problem is that everybody needs to know that feature

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [OData Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com) to create a query that does this.

Keep in mind that the data can be up to a month old.

Comment: Well yes, but how does this help the common SO user? I don't see the benefit in finding my own unanswered questions with a query. I want other users to see and answer them